# Remove records from a Dataframe with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file containing three columns. This link shows how my Dataframe is organized: https://github.com/phdvidal92/Files/blob/master/Data_Qnty.csv.

I would like to let just some records presented. For the SectionA, values equals to "Propose" and for the SectionB just "Prospecting".

I'm importing it with pandas read_csv

```
arqv2 = pd.read_csv('Data_Qnty.csv', skiprows = 2,
                    delimiter = ',', encoding = 'latin1')
```

After it, i'm trying to use drop

```
arqv2 = arqv2.drop(arqv2[(arqv2['SectionA'] != 'Prospecting') && (arqv2['SectionB'] != 'Propose')].index)
```

And it's not working. Do you know how can i achive my objective?

Thanks!

Comment: Text "it's not working" is the most useless information. Create short example data and expected result - and put it as text in question.

Comment: did you check `arqv2.head()` to see what you have ? If you `skiprows=2` then you skip headers and your DF doesn't use names `'SectionA'` `'SectionB'`. Maybe you should read all and later drop rows to keep headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want change the same dataframe, use `inplace=True` as second argument of `drop()`, and use the `&` operator, not `&&`, like this:

```
arqv2.drop(
    arqv2[(arqv2['SectionA'] != 'Prospecting') & 
          (arqv2['SectionB'] != 'Propose')].index, 
    inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks Hildeberto, do you know why we need to use inplace = True?

Comment: Was not working because of "&&". Use `inplace=True` for performance and better memory usage. It's don't make a copy of dataframe, and affect the underlying data. It's a parameter for various functions (replace, dropna, etc.). If you can not use inplace=True, use an assignment instead, to make a dataframe copy.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use `query`:

```
df.query('SectionA == "Propose" and SectionB =="Prospecting"')
```

Another method is to use boolean indexing:

```
df[(df['SectionA']  == 'Propose') & (df['SectionB'] == 'Prospecting')]
```